# attr titleTextColor conflict between appcompat_v7 and squareup-timesquare

Tags: android, eclipse, android-appcompat

I'm setting up a project both dependent on `appcompat_v7` and Android Times Square ([`com.squareup.timessquare`](https://github.com/square/android-times-square)). Whenever I'm trying to run my project, I end up with an error message from either the `appcompat_v7` or the times square, like here below:

```
/Users/meee/Documents/workspace/TimesSquare/res/values/attrs.xml:8: error: Attribute "titleTextColor" has already been defined
```

```
/Users/meee/Documents/workspace/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values/attrs.xml:832: error: Attribute "titleTextColor" has already been defined
```

I tried removing the `titleTextColor` attribute from either library, and it ends up ruining the `timessquare` or the `appcompat` when I refresh and clean it, depending whose `titleTextColor` I remove.

**Feel free to flag, but please explain.** Most conflicts like these are posted as issues on GitHub like [this](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary/issues/289), so I'd understand if you flag this question as inappropriate. Though I posted it here, thinking that in this case, it might be a non-issue for `timessquare` or `appcompat_v7`.

My support library is 23.1.1

Much appreciated, guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try renaming titleTextColor from TimesSquare/res/values/attrs.xml to titleTextColorx and change 
titleTextColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.CalendarPickerView_tsquare_titleTextColorx from com/squareup/timessquare/CalendarPickerView.java